# Change Table row color with css selectors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my CSS for changing table row colors:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
       background-color: #cceeff;   /* Blue color */


}

.accepted.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
       background-color: #ccffaa; /* green color */


}
```

the second selector does not have any effect.
i want the rows with accepted  class to be green, so how can i do this ?

edit : 
https://jsfiddle.net/qaueqe6u/

Comment: could you post your html? better in jsfiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something?

```css
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
  background-color: #cceeff; /* blue */
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr.accepted > td {
  background-color: #ccffaa; /* green */
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ><td>Reza</td></tr>
        <tr ><td>Reza</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Reza</td></tr>
        <tr class="accepted"><td>Reza</td></tr>
        <tr class="accepted"><td>Reza</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qaueqe6u/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the rows with the "accepted" class to be green, this css is wrong because you're assuming that the class will be together with the '.table-striped' class, that's used on the table element, not on the rows. Check this simple fiddle to better understand:

https://jsfiddle.net/gmmbuer8/

Since you're only wanting to target the row, the right CSS would be:

```
.table-striped > tbody > .accepted {
   background-color: #ccffaa; /* green color */
}
```

The ':nth-child(odd)' bit is only if you want it to have that 'striped' effect.

Comment: i want the rows with table-striped and accepted class to be green.

Comment: And that's exactly what happens in the fiddle I provided you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.table-striped.accepted > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
   background-color: #ccffaa; /* green color */
}
```

Comment: @ReZa Why do you use a bunch of odds etc? Seems to only complicate things. It's unclear what your desired behavior is.